# Is it possible to read HTML tables into pandas with style tag?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to use pandas `read_html` function to read the "Official List of the House of Representatives," located [here](http://clerk.house.gov/member_info/olmbr.aspx).

Using

```
df_list = pd.read_html('http://clerk.house.gov/member_info/olmbr.aspx',header=0,encoding = "UTF-8")
house = df_list[0]
```

I do get a nice DataFrame with the representatives name, state, and district. The header is correct and the encoding also. So far so good.

However, the problem is the party. There is no column for the party. Instead, the party is denoted by the font (roman or italic). Looking at the HTML source, here's an entry for a democrat:

```
<tr><td><em>Adams, Alma S.</em></td><td>NC</td><td>12th</td></tr>
```

and here's an entry for a republican:

```
<tr><td>Anderholt, Robert B.</td><td>AL</td><td>4th</td></tr>
```

Republicans are lacking the `<em></em>` tags around their name.

How would one go about retrieving this information? Can it be done with pandas or do I need some more sophisticated HTML parsers? If so, which ones?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'll have to manually write your own parser.

Comment: As far as getting the data, I have found a solution. There is a table in plain text format [here] (http://clerk.house.gov/member_info/text-labels-115.txt). I can read it with `house = pd.read_csv(URL,sep='\t',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`

Answer (score 6):

I think you need create parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://clerk.house.gov/member_info/olmbr.aspx"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
#print (table)

data = []
#remove first header 
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    #get all children tags of first td
    childrens = cols[0].findChildren()
    #extracet all tags joined by ,
    a = ', '.join([x.name for x in childrens]) if len(childrens) > 0 else ''

    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    #add tag value for each row
    cols.append(a)
    data.append(cols)
```

---

```
#DataFrame contructor
cols = ['Representative', 'State', 'District', 'Tag']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print (df.head())
        Representative State District Tag
0   Abraham, Ralph Lee    LA      5th    
1       Adams, Alma S.    NC     12th  em
2  Aderholt, Robert B.    AL      4th    
3        Aguilar, Pete    CA     31st  em
4       Allen, Rick W.    GA     12th
```

---

Also is possible create columns with `1` and `0` for all possible tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://clerk.house.gov/member_info/olmbr.aspx"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
#print (table)

data = []
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    childrens = cols[0].findChildren()
    a = '|'.join([x.name for x in childrens]) if len(childrens) > 0 else ''
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    cols.append(a)
    data.append(cols)

cols = ['Representative', 'State', 'District', 'Tag']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df = df.join(df.pop('Tag').str.get_dummies())
print (df.head())
        Representative State District  em  strong
0   Abraham, Ralph Lee    LA      5th   0       0
1       Adams, Alma S.    NC     12th   1       0
2  Aderholt, Robert B.    AL      4th   0       0
3        Aguilar, Pete    CA     31st   1       0
4       Allen, Rick W.    GA     12th   0       0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for clear and instructive example of HTML scraping

Comment: Minor correction. The code as given by @jezrael will not read accented characters properly. This can be fixed by `soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')`